# Weight Paint Problems

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

[Link to the file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CL1vz-TE52nkvyK6aDs268PHjIFtQ96R?usp=sharing)

I'm pretty new to blender. When I use keep parent automatic weights, somehow the bone on the neck has some weight on its right finger. But when I erase the weight paint, the bone for the head has some weight paint on the same place. And the weird thing is when I erase the weight paint from the head bone, it appears again at the same place for the neck bone. I don't know how to solve this.

[image]

So the neck-bone has weight pain on its right hand.

[image: third pic]

And then I erase it

[image]

When I select the head-bone, there is also weight paint on its right hand

[image]

I erase it as well.

[image]

But it appears at the same place for the neck-bone again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the *Auto Normalize* option and paint:

[image]

Also do you really need so many polygons? I won't make the animation easy, you'd better give your character object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I am using the multires modifier because it is easier to sculpt. Do you have any recommendations of making a model or some ways to make a model with fewer polygons?

Comment: create a low-poly object, use a Subdivision Surface modifier to make it rounder, don't apply the modifier, put it under the Armature modifier. With your current object you could try a Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide, and tweak the Iterations value in the Operator box (try 6), then give it the Subdivision Surface modifier (with a level of 2)

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!